# query for sql server 2005 for getting the 95th percentile of different groups

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, percentile

I have a table like the dummy table described below

### Date || Server || Count

---

### 1200          || B        || 123

### 1200          || C        || 124

### 1200          || B        || 125

### 1300          || B        || 126

### 1300          || C        || 127

### 1300          || B        || 128

### 1300          || C        || 129

I need to write a query to create a table such that I get the 95 percentile of the Count grouped by both Date and Server.

I dont have much experience with Sql, and after looking at the google search results, surfing through countless links I am a bit terrified after seeing a lot of subqueries used.No one is able to give a simple query. Can't we directly use a direct query to get the result like the following?

### Date       || Server    || Count

---

### 1200          || B        || 123

### 1200          || C        || 124

### 1300          || B        || 126

### 1300          || C        || 127

Can some one please provide the exact query which can be used?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, NTILE(20) OVER (PARTITION BY [date], [server] ORDER BY [count]) AS t
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   t < 20
```